# Angular Material: md-datepicker CSS empty display issue

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-material, display

I've upgraded to Angular Material 1.1.1. I'm using Angular JS v1.6.1.

The issue I have is when I use the standard code as follows:

```
<md-content>
  <h4>Standard date-picker</h4>
  <md-datepicker ng-model="test" placeholder="Test date"></md-datepicker>
</md-content>
```

When I select the picker, I get an empty div that is loaded only when i scroll.

**Image below:**

[empty datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPQC7.png)

**Codepen:**

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MJaBxZ?editors=1000)

Answer (score 0):

There are already multipe github issues for this, you don't need to create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's true, I'm sorry. Here is the link to the issue at github.

[Github issue](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/10168#issuecomment-268886473)